# How to trigger XMLStreamException in Test class

Tags: java, xml, unit-testing

I need to cover `XMLStreamException` in my JUnit but I don't know how to trigger this exception.

Here's my code snippet in my class:

```
try {
    writer.add(factory.createStartElement("", "", BatchConstants.HEADER));
    writer.add(factory.createStartElement("", "", BatchConstants.MESSAGE_TYPE));
    writer.add(factory.createCharacters(BatchConstants.LPR_ENTITY));
    writer.add(factory.createEndElement("", "", BatchConstants.MESSAGE_TYPE));
    writer.add(factory.createStartElement("", "", BatchConstants.SEND_DATETIME));
    writer.add(factory.createCharacters(batchProcessControlEntity.getCreatedDt().toString()));
    writer.add(factory.createEndElement("", "", BatchConstants.SEND_DATETIME));
    writer.add(factory.createEndElement("", "", BatchConstants.HEADER));
} catch (XMLStreamException e) {
    this.logger.logError(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

I can cover the test of the above snippet by using this:

```
@Test
public void testWrite() throws IOException, XMLStreamException {

    BatchProcessControlEntity batchProcessControlEntity = new BatchProcessControlEntity();
    batchProcessControlEntity.setCreatedDt(new Date());
    Mockito.when(this.batchProcessControlJpaRepository.findByBatchProcessCtrlId(Matchers.anyObject()))
        .thenReturn(batchProcessControlEntity);

    XMLEventWriter eventWriter = Mockito.mock(XMLEventWriter.class);

    this.headerWriter.write(eventWriter);
}
```

But I don't know what input do I need to trigger `XMLStreamException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the doThrow method of mockito.

- Nice [tutorial here](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-exceptions)
- doThrow [javaDoc here](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.24.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doThrow-java.lang.Throwable...-)

Some sample code for fun:

```
XMLEventWriter eventWriter = Mockito.mock(XMLEventWriter.class);
doThrow(new XMLStreamException("This is my exception"))
        .when(eventWriter)
        .add(any(XMLEvent.class));
```

Comment: I'm always a bit distrustful that this is an accurate simulation. Very often the problem with exception handling is with the state of the object that threw the exception (e.g. are further reads or writes possible). Mocking an exception enables you to get code coverage for your "catch" blocks, but I'm not sure it really gives you confidence that your code can actually recover from, say, a disk full error.

Comment: @MichaelKay - you're not wrong, but this is obviously a first step not a last.